# Android ListView index changes when last row is interacted

Tags: android, listview

trying to build a type of resulttracker I've encounterde this problem;

I have one custom listview (with a header) where each player get a row. In this row there is a TextView for name and one EditText for the number of throws (among others).

When running on the emulator everything runs fine, in all cases.

When running on the phone and not changing any values everything runs fine.

When running on the phone and reporting a value in the last row of the ListView the code skipps the first item and thus get a null pointer exception when trying to find the last row.

Reporting the results is done by this method:

```
    private void reportResults(ListView listViewPlayers, ArrayList<HoleResultInfo> holeResult_data, TextView tvPar, Integer hole){
    //Skapar arrya ifrån antalet spelare i tabellen, justerar för header 
    System.out.println("gui hol Collecting hole results");
    System.out.println("gui hol number of items in listview: " + listViewPlayers.getCount());

    HoleResultInfo tempHoleResult;
    for (int i = 0; i < listViewPlayers.getCount()-1; i++) {
        tempHoleResult = holeResult_data.get(i);
        //Starts at 1 to skip header
        View rowView = listViewPlayers.getChildAt(i+1);
        System.out.println("gui hol At i: " + i + " looking for child: " + (i + 1));
        System.out.println("gui hol HoleResult name: " + holeResult_data.get(i).getName());
        TextView tvName = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);
        System.out.println("gui hol Textview name: " + tvName.getText().toString());
            tempHoleResult.setName(tvName.getText().toString());
        EditText etOb = (EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.etPlayerOb);
            tempHoleResult.setOb(Integer.parseInt(etOb.getText().toString()));
        EditText etTrows = (EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.etPlayerTrows);
            tempHoleResult.setTrows(Integer.parseInt(etTrows.getText().toString()));

        holeResult_data.set(i, tempHoleResult);
    }
```

The output from the logcat (having three players: Otto, Teddy and Test) is as follows in emulator and not reporting:

```
gui hol Collecting hole results
gui hol number of items in listview: 4
gui hol At i: 0 looking for child: 1
gui hol HoleResult name: Otto
gui hol Textview name: Otto
gui hol At i: 1 looking for child: 2
gui hol HoleResult name: Teddy
gui hol Textview name: Teddy
gui hol At i: 2 looking for child: 3
gui hol HoleResult name: Test
gui hol Textview name: Test
```

And this is the output when not working:

```
gui hol Collecting hole results 
gui hol number of items in listview: 4
gui hol At i: 0 looking for child: 1
gui hol HoleResult name: Otto
gui hol Textview name: Teddy
gui hol At i: 1 looking for child: 2
gui hol HoleResult name: Teddy
gui hol Textview name: Test
gui hol At i: 2 looking for child: 3
gui hol HoleResult name: Test
D/AndroidRuntime(15847): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(15847): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41541318)
E/AndroidRuntime(15847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15847): java.lang.NullPointerException
at frisbeegolf.gui.Hole.reportResults(Hole.java:141)
at frisbeegolf.gui.Hole.access$0(Hole.java:129)
at frisbeegolf.gui.Hole$1.onClick(Hole.java:69)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4103)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17117)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

Row 141 is: TextView tvName = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);

Please help, I'm all out of ideas and going nuts over this!

/O

Answer (score 0):

Method getChildAt() gets on of **visible** views

```
View rowView = listViewPlayers.getChildAt(i+1);
```

You shoud change data on your data list e.g ArrayList, and then notify ListView by calling notifydataSetChange method from your list adapter

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

Your adapter should change all data in visible cells by calling method getView, but it is not attached in your question

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I'm not sure that I understand your answer. I've never had any problems to get the correct number, it is getting the right row that fails.